# Url Rewrite: Should www re-writing be in the app or the web server?

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I have to redirect non-www urls to use www.  I have a choice of doing this in IIS 7 or code this logic in my ASP.Net application.

In terms of portability I would've thought writing this in the application itself might be better.

Is there a preferred method for achieving this or is it just preference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this in IIS7, all it does is modify your Web.Config files for you. I would have said that that was the conventional way of doing things.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Oh dear, can't believe I forgot about that, of course, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is more rational to do this in the application. For example we have it defined like that:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "User", // Route name
            "u/{user}/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Hence we have plenty of flexibility and can have specific tokens in our links, etc. Yet if there was no need for that - we would use IIS base. So, I guess - whatever tickles your pickle here :)